# Build a Turing machine to prove that a problem is $NL$

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, space-complexity

If we the language $A$, which is defined like this:
$$A = \{\langle G,s,t \rangle \} \mid \text{ There is a maximum path in graph $G$ that begin in $s$} \} $$
I want to build a Turing Machine that decides $A$ to prove that $A\in NL$.
How can we build the machine?
I try this:

1. Begin from $s$ and choose a neighbour $u$ of $s$
2. If $u$ have neighbours then return $1$
3. Else ...

How can we continue from here, is it the right way?

Comment: What you are trying to do is deterministic. You need a nondeterministic TM to approach this question

Comment: @nirshahar Maybe we need to choose arbitrary a neighbour and then to check?

Comment: check *what* exactly? How would this "check" help you solve this problem? Try to think on those two things a bit. It might help you

Comment: @nirshahar I try but I'm a bit stuck...

Comment: you could try writing a turing machine that accepts a certificate…